# constness it not propagated for dependent types

Tags: c++, c++14, c++17

Why is it that for

```
struct A { int a };   
using B = const A;    // or typedef const A B;
```

`decltype(B::a)` evaluates to `int` and not `const int`. 
What chapter of the *How to learn C++ in a life time* am I missing?

Comment: did you mean `decltype(B::a)`?

Comment: Yes, corrected!
I expected to turn return `const int` because  I assumed the const qualifier is considered as well? Hm...

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Assuming you meant `decltype(B::a)`, I do not see why you expect it to return `const int`.

`decltype(x)` roughly gives you the *"type `x` was declared as"*, which in this case is `int`.

Here's an interesting example:

```
int main()
{
    B x{};
    static_assert(std::is_same_v<decltype(x.a), int>); // (0)
    static_assert(std::is_same_v<decltype((x.a)), const int&>); // (1)
}
```

**(0)** tells you that the declared type of `x.a` is indeed `int`, even though `x` is `const`.

**(1)** tells you that the value category of `x.a` is an *lvalue*, which happens to be `const`.

*(Note that `decltype` [behaves differently with parenthesized expressions](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/decltype).)*